# ncat send lines in file as one line

Tags: logging, udp, syslog

I want transmit a log file with very long lines with ncat -u --send-only host port < log.txt ...

The problem is that send all lines as one, it doesn't honor new lines

I also tried -C but it makes it worst...

I can succeed with a while loop

```
  while read x;do echo $x|ncat -u --send-only host port;done < log.txt
```

But it takes too long.